# Regular exp to check minumum 200 characters, including spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a regular expression to check for a minimum of 200 characters, including spaces. It should accept any characters from the keyboard I am new to javascript. How do I do it?

Comment: I don't know javascript, but is a regexp the best approach?  Surely there's a length function.

Comment: I am using Javascript ValidationEngine.js where they use regular expressions. So I need to do it in regex

Comment: how about `maxlength` on input then ?

Comment: Yeah, a regex is overkill for something that doesn't actually need the "ex" part. Or the "reg" part.

Answer (score 3):

A regular expression which matches all characters, with a minimum of 200 is this one:

```
/[\S\s]{200,}/
```

- `\S` - Any non-whitespace characters
- `\s` - Any whitespace character
- `[\S\s]` - Any non-whitespace and whitespace character = any characters
- `[\S\s]{200,}` - Any character, at least 200 times.

Comment: does it matches 200 words or min 200 characters including spaces??

Comment: It matches **all** characters **including** whitespace - as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Of course, since you haven't anchored the regex (and the regex is just needed for validation), you could just as well write `/[\S\s]{200}/`, speeding up the match.

Comment: @Tim, good point. For that reason, I didn't add any parentheses, `^` or `$`.

Comment: @Rob, yeah, but your regex will still match the entire string (which may be millions of characters long for all we know) when it's perfectly OK to call it a day after the first 200.

Comment: Any particular reason to use `[\S\s]` instead of `.`?

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, `.` doesn't match *all* characters: The newline character, `\n`, doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to agree with the person that commented on your answer. A regular expression is not the way to go (at least with the limited information you have provdided). If you go to the [mdn entry on strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) you will see that every string in JavaScript has a property that you can access called "length" which tells you exactly how many characters/bytes the string is composed of. Like so:

```
var myNewString = 'foo and bar';
    myNewString.length //returns 11
    'foo and bar'.length //returns 11
```